# List of figures as a section with number

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, article

How can I get the list of figures as a section in an article document, so it will be listed in the table of contents? At the moment it's listed in the ToC, but without number.

Comment: Welcome to Tex! Why don't you try something like `\section{List of Figures}\lofwithouttitle\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List o Figures}`

Comment: @Thanos: You would also need `\makeatletter\newcommand{\lofwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lof}}\makeatother`.

Comment: @Werner:Yeas you are right...I forgot to copy it...Thank's and sorry for the inconvinience...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the default [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class `\listoffigures` is set as `\section*`, thereby removing it from being displayed in the ToC:

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
```

Modifying this to actually use `\section` instead inserts the appropriate numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\insertfigure}{\begin{figure}\caption{A figure caption}\end{figure}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section{\listfigurename}% Used to be \section*{\listfigurename}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\section{A section}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!  Also works when replacing `section` by `chapter`, for example for books.

Answer (score 5):

With the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes, simply use the class option `listof=totocnumbered`.

```
\documentclass[listof=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\section{foo}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which package do I need to use?